# The butterfly effect in Judaism

Tags: beis-hamikdash, yerushalayim-jerusalem

The "butterfly effect" is when very small changes produce very large effects.  In Judaism, the Talmud [Gittin 55b-56a; also Lamentations Rabbah 4:3] gives us an example: "The destruction of Jerusalem came through a Kamtza and a Bar Kamtza in this way."  A small backwater incident resulted in hundreds of thousands of dead Jews, large-scale destruction and the loss of the Second Temple.

What other examples of the butterfly effect do we know, in Judaism, according to the Sources?

I am not talking about answered prayers or Hashem saying "Let there be light".  Rather, I am talking about something like: if Joseph had agreed to become the secret lover of Potiphar's wife, he would not have gone to jail, would not have attracted Pharaoh's attention, would not have become viceroy, would not have brought his family to Egypt, and we would not have been enslaved.

**Added Note**:  You guys are right.  You can always say things like "If Lot had not slept with his daughter, we would not have had King David or the future Messiah."  We can speculate like so in our own lives.  I don't know how to phrase what I mean, except that I am talking about something VERY slight and subtle (like a butterfly flapping its wings in Brazil causing a tornado in Texas.)

Let me ask at least this:  Does it say anywhere else, in the Sources, *in very clear language, not implied*, "If this little thing hadn't happened, this other big thing wouldn't have either"?

Comment: The other two incidents in the cited Gemara in Gittin? I’m tempted to VTC as too broad or unclear; you haven’t suitably defined “small change” and “large effect.” Would you allow any case of someone davening for some large-scale event to occur, of which there are literally hundreds of such events in Tanach and Shas?

Comment: the gemara in kiddushin says "one should always look at himself as if he has half merits and half sins and the whole world is half tzadikim and half reshaim, do one mitzvah and tilt yourself and whole world to merit, one aveirah and tilt yourself and the whole world to side of bad" (40b)

Comment: “The butterfly effect... In Judaism...” Do you mean in Jewish sources, literature, history, Jewish life?

Comment: @DonielF -- "you haven’t suitably defined “small change” and “large effect.”  Sure I have.  I said "very" for both. :-)

Comment: @Oliver -- All of them, but preferably in the classical Sources.

Comment: I think the question is too broad because EVERY single story in the Torah is such an example - If the fruit would fall out of Eve's hands, or Adam would wait for Shabbos or G-d didn't make Cain mad and kill Ebel or Adam didn't come back to Eve and make Shes etc.

Comment: Since the first time in history man listened to woman all of humanity has suffered. There’s your butterfly effect.

Comment: If you don’t know how to phrase what you’re asking, how do you expect anyone to come up with a satisfactory answer?

Comment: @DonielF -- I guess I was naive enough to think this could be a collaborative effort.

Comment: @MauriceMizrahi We’re all happy to help, but you have to give us something to work with

Comment: Please don't cause any tornadoes in Texas. :)

Comment: @Maurice Mizrahi I am still intrigued by this question and believe there must be a way to make it work. To start out, can we differentiate a little better between the example of what you are looking for (Yosef succumbing to the advances of Potifar's wife and not going to prison) and the example of what you're not looking for (Lot sleeping with his daughters)?

Comment: How about "if Reuven had not gone flowerpicking one afternoon, Leah would not have been able to barter the dudaim for an extra evening with Yaakov and Issachar would not have been born"?

Answer (score 1):

There are midrashim (I learned this through a series by Rabbi David Fohrman) which suggest that Sarah's harsh treatment of Hagar (though Hagar fully deserved it) led to the Jewish people being enslaved in Egypt.

On a more pshat level, you could also look at Yosef bragging about his dreams as leading to the Jewish people being enslaved in Egypt, the 10 plagues, and the parting of Yam Suf.

Answer (score 1):

If Esav hadn't gone out and vigorously worshipped idols, murderded a man, and commited adultery on the day of his grandfather Abraham's funeral, then he wouldn't have  been famished enough to sell his birthright for a bowl of red lentils and would have gone on to marry Leah and father half of the Tribes of Israel (if that is even the correct term!)